# recover data from an .xls in spring mvc4 + jsp + mysql + jpa2.1

Tags: mysql, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have to make a program in j2ee: spring mvc4 + jsp + mysql + jpa2.1
in this application I must recover data from an .xls file and these data must be saved in the MySQL database (in several tables) to use them throughout the rest of the realized application.
can you help me know where to start and how to proceed. I did alot of search but I do not have a good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I approach for this kind of project.

1. JSP page. Just to upload .xls file.
2. Spring Controller to get/download that excel file and put it in some location of server.

   - Any preferred API that can parse excel file.
   - Various Pojos bidden with database.
   - Controller logic that extract data from excel to pojo.
   - Logic to Save tat data to database.
3. Other UIs/Logic that will use this db data for business logic.